# Render html file in HTML5

Tags: html, render

Can I import/render a HTML file inside other HTML file?

Main file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div><!-- render other HTML file here --></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Render file:

```
<h1>Testing</h1>
```

Final expected result:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div><h1>Testing</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use an  iframe?

Comment: I don't want a frame, I wanna just organize better my HTML code files

Comment: you need to use JS or server-side technology if you want to do this.  HTML files are static by default, if you want to load dynamic bits of your HTML, you need something else to help you with that

Comment: I think you'll want to look at something like Web Components (https://www.webcomponents.org/), Polymer (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/), Handlebars (http://handlebarsjs.com/), or a JS framework like React, Angular, VueJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that so neatly with plain HTML. You would need a renderer like Node.js or Django which preprocess the page for you and send a response to the client like the one you desire.

Alternatively you could use JavaScript to gather the page through AJAX and write it on that spot. But I don't think that's worth it.

But you can use iframes to achieve more or less the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Use an iframe with your other page's url :

 `<iframe src="http://www.yourotherpage.com"></iframe>`

Comment: OP said no frames :(

Comment: Didn't saw while I was writing